# how to get previous page with search_after elasticsearch with java client?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, pagination

**using search_after**

1. i have more than 100,000 documents on elasticsearch and i need to get previous page and forward page
2. but my problem is i cannot get previous page with search_After. is it possible to use search_After with from to size to pagination more than 10,000 documents? or do i other options?
3. i tried using search_after java code and sort fileds are userId and date(HH:mm:ss.SSS) but when i click previous button or jump to  page 1 to page 5, its not showing proper values